# Custom post type editor with dynamic selects, one drop down populating a second second drop down not working

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, ajax, wp-admin

I have a custom post type where I am attempting to have one select populate the options of a second select in the custom post type's editor.

The first drop down pulls in a list of tags associated to a different custom post type. The second drop down is suppose return a list of the other custom post type's posts that have the selected tag assigned to them.

This is my first attempt using Ajax and Jquery. I have read the docs at the codex regarding Ajax and have spent the better part of four days trying to find a solution on google stack exchange etc.

When I view the page in console I can see under post my value and action are being sent and under response I see that I am getting a 0 returned.

My first drop down renders as expected as does the one that is to be dynamically populated. When I make a selection in first drop drop down the second drop down does show in the source code that the response "0" is being placed between the select's opening and closing tags but no options are being returned.

Thanks in advance for help about what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php
// This is the function that is suppose to handle the Ajax Request/Response

add_action( 'wp_ajax_dynamic_dropdown_func', 'dynamic_dropdown_func' );
function dynamic_dropdown_func () {
global $wpdb;
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $selected_option = $_POST['value'];
    // This is my second dropdown here, this will be returned in an Ajax request
    $args = array(
    'show_option_none' => __( 'Pick Another One' ),
    'class' => 'dropper',
    'id' => 'dropper0',
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'sort_order'   => 'ASC',
    'sort_column'  => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'exercise-videos'
    );

    $my_second_dropdown = wp_dropdown_pages( $args );

}

//ob_clean is to prevent errors, echos, anything that has outputted to this point in the Ajax WP instance that could ruin your return.
    ob_clean();
echo $my_second_dropdown;

wp_die();
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here

function my_action_javascript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Now lets grab our dropdowns
            dropdownArome   = jQuery('#arome0'),
            dropdownDropper = jQuery('#dropper0');

        if (dropdownArome.length && dropdownDropper.length) {
            // Good, our elements exist
            dropdownArome.on('change', function (e) {
                var value = e.target.selectedOptions[0].value,
                    success,
                    data;
                if (!!value) {
                    // Alright, lets send that value to our Ajax Script, note that the action is the same as the Ajax action hook we used earlier
                    data = {
                        'my_value' : value,
                        'action'   : 'dynamic_dropdown_func'
                    };
                    success = function ( response ) {
                        // This response will hold our <option>'s
                        dropdownDropper.html( response );
                    };
                    jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, success );
                }
            });
        }

});
</script> <?php
}

/** This is where I am building my dropdowns */

$args = array(
'show_option_none' => __( 'Filter Videos' ),
'class' => 'arome',
'id' => 'arome0',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => 0,
'hierarchical' => 1,
'depth' => 1,
'echo' => 0,
'taxonomy' => 'exercise-videos_tag',
);

$my_first_dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );


// Now I am printing out the 2 dropdowns
echo $my_first_dropdown;
echo '<br /><div id="dropper0-container"><select name="exercise_video_id" id="dropper0" data-placeholder="Choose videos..." class="dropper"></select></div><br />';
```

Comment: What file contains this code? You have a lot of code here that just outputs directly to the page, so it's likely your AJAX code is not in the right place. It has to be hooked on the AJAX request, not the request you make the AJAX call from. The page that renders your CPT and the AJAX request are two different http requests. Also note that your AJAX function should echo, not return.

Comment: Hi Milo, It is the plugin's main file it's part of another function that is adding a custom meta box to the custom post types editor page. I will move the function dynamic_drop_down and the js out of that parent function. I will also change the return to an echo.

Comment: zero tends to means no ajax response... why is `my_ajax_dynamic_dropdown_func` different to `dynamic_dropdown_func`? that could be it...

Comment: Hi majick, Good question... I think that was me being sloppy. I changed it so the they are the same. How ever since doing that I am not getting a response at all. Not even zero. There is not even a response tab in the console.